# Can not delete item from local storage in browser

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, google-chrome, local-storage

I am developing automated tests using Selenium in Java. I want to delete local and session storage, cookies etc. to have "clear" WebDriver. I need it to logout from the site and use the same WebDriver for all tests instead of closing and opening browser for each test case.

When I delete the whole local storage as is shown on the picture - it is deleted. Then I reload the page. I am not logged out and all local storage items appear again.

[image]

Then I delete only active_user_session item using 'delete' key on keyboard. Then I immediately find myself logged out.

This is strange thing... Why when I delete all storage I am not logged out and information was restored when I reload the page. But when I delete only one active_user_session item I was logged out immedeately???

Ok. Let's go to the code.

```
((JavascriptExecutor)(driver)).executeScript( String.format(
                "window.localStorage.removeItem('%s');", "access_token"
        ));
```

This one works fine. But I need to delete active_user_session item it seems...

```
((JavascriptExecutor)(driver)).executeScript( String.format(
                "window.localStorage.removeItem('%s');", "active_user_session"
        ));
```

This code does not work: active_user_session is still there!!!

The more funny thing:

```
    ((JavascriptExecutor)(driver)).executeScript(
            "window.localStorage.clear();"
    );
```

Deletes all except active_user_session item!

Whyy??? Can you explain please? May be I don't know something...
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
 driver.getSessionStorage().clear();
 driver.getLocalStorage().clear();
```

for more information about this, you check the [link](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/html5/SessionStorage.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The same thing. Not all was cleared.

Comment: try removing all cookies as well using        `driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();`

Answer (score 0):

Try this - will clear everything from your browser the good old fashioned way - but completely automated otherwise (i.e. cookies, logins, etc. will all be requested again)...

```
#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54404721/can-not-delete-item-from-local-storage-in-browser/54415520#54415520
import time, os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import JavascriptException

def new_profile():
    global ev, parent, d, w
    global path_core, path_exec
    global ev


    path_core= os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), 'Folder_Path_to_your_Code')
    path_exec =  os.path.join(path_core, "chromedriver.exe") #assumes chromedriver.exe saved in same location as your code...
    d = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path_exec)
    [ev] = [d.execute_script]
    parent = d.current_window_handle
    w = WebDriverWait(d,5)
    
    #d.implicitly_wait(0.5)
    print('new profile complete')


def browser_clear(url=''):
    global start, ss, w
    [ss] = [time.sleep]
    w_old, w = w, WebDriverWait(d, 20)
    url = d.current_url if url == ''else url 
    script0 = '''document.querySelector('body').querySelector('settings-ui')["shadowRoot"].querySelector('settings-main')['shadowRoot'].querySelector('settings-basic-page')['shadowRoot'].querySelector('settings-privacy-page')['shadowRoot'].querySelector('#pages').querySelector('#clearBrowsingData')['shadowRoot'].lastElementChild.click()'''
    script1 = '''document.querySelector('body').querySelector('settings-ui')["shadowRoot"].querySelector('settings-main')['shadowRoot'].querySelector('settings-basic-page')['shadowRoot'].querySelector('settings-privacy-page')['shadowRoot'].querySelector('settings-clear-browsing-data-dialog')['shadowRoot'].querySelector('iron-pages').querySelector('#basic-tab').querySelector('settings-dropdown-menu')['shadowRoot'].lastElementChild.selectedIndex = 4;'''
    script2 = '''document.querySelector('body').querySelector('settings-ui')["shadowRoot"].querySelector('settings-main')['shadowRoot'].querySelector('settings-basic-page')['shadowRoot'].querySelector('settings-privacy-page')['shadowRoot'].querySelector('settings-clear-browsing-data-dialog')['shadowRoot'].querySelector('#clearBrowsingDataDialog').children[3].lastElementChild.parentElement.children[2].click()'''
    script_wait = '''{if (document.querySelector('body').querySelector('settings-ui')["shadowRoot"].querySelector('settings-main')['shadowRoot'].querySelector('settings-basic-page')['shadowRoot'].querySelector('settings-privacy-page')['shadowRoot'].querySelector('settings-clear-browsing-data-dialog')) {return true} else {return false}}'''
    d.get('chrome://settings/')
    ev(script0)
    start = time.time()
    while (time.time() - start <= 30) and ev(script_wait) == False: ss(0.5)
    ss(1)
    ev(script1), ss(0.5), ev(script2)
    start = time.time()
    while (time.time() - start <= 180) and ev(script_wait) == True: ss(0.5)
    try:
        d.get(url)
    except TimeoutError:
        w.until(lambda x: x.execute_script("return document.readyState") == "complete")
    w = w_old
    d.get(url)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    new_profile()
    browser_clear()
```